# Hot to get data from webapge using selenium and show it using flask?

Tags: python, selenium, flask, selenium-webdriver

Hello I'm a theologian and one of the things that I usually have to do is translate from latin to english or spanish. In order to do that I use an online dictionary and check if an specific word is in nominative case or dative case (latinist stuff)...

Now I'd code a simple script in python using selenium that get the dictionary's page and extract the case of the word. All works fine and as I want to, but...

Always there is a 'but' haha. I want to take that data that I extract by using selenium and 'print' it by using flask in a webpage. I code that, but it doesn't work...

my code:

```
from flask import Flask
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from tabulate import tabulate
import sys
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

chrome_opt = Options()
chrome_opt.binary_location = g_chrome_bin = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
chrome_opt.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_opt.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_opt.add_argument('--disable-dev-sh--usage')

selenium_driver_path = os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= selenium_driver_path if selenium_driver_path else "./chromedriver", options=chrome_opt)

def analyze (words):
    ws = words.split()
    sentence = []
    for w in ws:
        driver.get('http://archives.nd.edu/cgi-bin/wordz.pl?keyword=' + w)
        pre = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//pre')
        sentence = sentence + [[w] + [ pre.text.replace('.', '') ]]
    return tabulate(sentence, headers=["Word", "Dictionary"])

#analyze("pater noster qui est in celis")

@app.route("/api/<string:ws>")
def api (ws):
    return analyze(ws)

driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And when I go to `http://localhost:5000/api/pater` (for ex.) I've got **Internal Server Error** and in the console **selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You close your driver session (`driver.close()`)before the main method runs. Thus when you make an api request and try to call `driver.get()` that driver is already closed. Eather you initialise a new driver for every call to `analazye()` and close that at the end of the method OR you dont close the driver session at all.